# Export gpg to p12 under windows

Tags: windows, encryption, gnupg

I'm using gpg4win and I'm trying to export my gpg private key to a p12 format (to import it in Lotus Notes). According to my understanding I need to:

```
gpgsm.exe -o "XXXXXXXX_private.p12" --export-secret-key-p12 0xXXXXXXXX
```

However, I'm getting the following error : "No secret Key"
Actually, gpgsm -K does not return anything at all (where gpg -K works).

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong program; `pgpsm` is used to *sign, check, encrypt or decrypt using the S/MIME protocol*.

I do not have `pgp4win` at hand, but according to the [man page](https://supportimg.pgp.com/guides/PGP_Command_Line_8.5_man_page.html), this should export your public and secret key:

```
gpg -o XXXXXXX_private.p12 --export [key id] --export-format pkcs12 --cert
```

The info on `pkcs12` is the following,

> `pkcs12` Only binary blocks are output; the default file extension is
>   .p12; a signed key must be paired; and input must match exactly one
>   key.   In this case, --cert is required.

so I included the `--cert` option, without reflection about that option:

> `--cert` This option is the X.509 issuer long name or the 32-bit or 64-bit key ID, if the signing key is available.

---

I did some more tests (now with gpg4win), and partially have to contradict myself. The `gpgsm` tool in gpg4win describes itself as

> gpgsm  is a tool similar to gpg to provide digital encryption and sign-
>          ing services on X.509 certificates and the CMS protocol.  It is  mainly
>          used  as  a  backend for S/MIME mail processing.

which indeed sounds correct.

So, your command posted in the question seems totally sensible, I only have two more clues:

- You can try to use a ASCII armored output via the `-a` option
- And there is an option concerning the charset of the exported key, which often is a problem with (especially older) windows programs:

> `--p12-charset name`
>                 gpgsm  uses  the  **UTF-8**  encoding  when encoding passphrases for
>                 PKCS#12 files.  This option may be used to force the  passphrase
>                 to be encoded in the specified encoding name.  **This is useful if
>                 the application used to import the key uses a different encoding
>                 and  thus  will not be able to import a file generated by gpgsm.**
>                 Commonly used values for name are **Latin1** and **CP850**.   Note  that
>                 gpgsm  itself  automagically  imports any file with a passphrase
>                 encoded to the most commonly used encodings.

Comment: Ok I now get the difference between gpg and gpgsm, thanks. However, this command does not work '--export-key-pair' is not a valid option. I have tried --export but then it won't import in Lotus Notes (but the problem might be in Lotus Notes).

Comment: @Choumarin: Sorry, the gpg of gpg4win and the linux version seem to differ significantly. I updated my answer, but I have no possibility to test with Lotus.

Answer (score 1):

Might be just that the answer refers to an older version of the program, but I was able to export using this command

```
gpgsm -o output.p12 --export-secret-key-p12 [keyID]
```